# Multiple TS step definitions in ESM project

Tags: node.js, cucumberjs

I have an ESM project (so `"type": "module"` in my `package.json`).
I want to write tests with cucumber and I would like my steps definition to be in ts.

I have this structure :

```
- package.json
- test
 - features
   - thing1.feature
   - thing2.feature
 - steps
   - thing1.ts
   - thing2.ts
   - common.ts
```

I followed the [documentation](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-js/blob/main/docs/transpiling.md#with-ts-node) and my script is :
`cross-env NODE_OPTIONS="--loader ts-node/esm" cucumber-js test/features/*.feature --import test/steps/*.ts`.

If I have a single ts file in steps folder, everything works great. If I add another file, I have a weird cucumber error.

`Error: The uri (test/steps/thing1.ts) must end with .feature or .md`.

Am I missing something ?

Comment: Your script uses `--import` while the docs you linked use `--require`. You should follow the docs. Or if you are using ESM somehow I think you'll want these docs https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-js/blob/8c0ee1d5346f87b74f56f6f5e15c33b2adc565ad/docs/esm.md.